# How to filter/render items based on dropdown value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects and I want to filter some items out of it and render it in the view based on a dropdown that has a value (which is also managed by state).

The array looks like this:

```
const arr = [
  {
    departmentName: 'Operations',
    jobs: [
      {
        url: 'https:...',
        description: '....',
        department: 'Operations'
        location: 'New York, NY'
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    departmentName: 'Brand Marketing',
    jobs: [
      {
        url: 'https:...',
        description: '....',
        department: 'Brand Marketing'
        location: 'New York, NY'
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    departmentName: 'Brand Marketing',
    jobs: [
      {
        url: 'https:...',
        description: '....',
        department: 'Brand Marketing'
        location: 'Austin, TX'
      }
    ],
  },
  ....
];
```

So far, in my view, I'm able to render all of data:

```
type DepartmentJob = {
  departmentName: string;
  jobs: Job[];
};

export type Job = {
  applyUrl: string;
  department: string;
  description: string;
  id: string;
  location: string;
  order: any;
  title: string;
};


class View extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  public constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedLocation: 'All Locations'
    }
  }

  public render() {
    const { locations, careers } = this.props;
    const { selectedLocation } = this.state;

      return (
        <Container>
          <Select
            label={selectedLocation}
            options={locations}
            onChange={(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => this.handleChange(e.currentTarget.value)}
            value={selectedLocation}
          />
          {careers.map((career: DepartmentJob) =>
            <DepartmentContainer key={career.departmentName}>
              <DepartmentName>{career.departmentName}</DepartmentName>
              <JobsContainer>
                {career.jobs.map(({ title, id, location }: Job) =>
                  <Card
                    key={id}
                    id={id}
                    title={title}
                    location={location}
                  />,
                )}
              </JobsContainer>
            </DepartmentContainer>,
          )}
        </Container>
      )
    }

  private handleChange = (selectedLocation: string) =>
    this.setState({ selectedLocation });
}
```

So now I want to filter these based on the `Select`, or Dropdown, which is also handled by state. The current way I'm handling this is like this:

```
public render() {
    const { locations, careers } = this.props;
    const { selectedLocation } = this.state;
      if (this.state.selectedLocation !== 'All Locations') {

      return ( 
        <Container>
          <Select
            label={selectedLocation}
            options={locations}
            onChange={(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => this.handleChange(e.currentTarget.value)}
            value={selectedLocation}
          />
          {careers.filter((career: DepartmentJob) =>
            career.jobs.some((job: Job) => job.location === selectedLocation)
          ).map((filteredJob: DepartmentJob) =>
            <DepartmentContainer key={filteredJob.departmentName}>
              <DepartmentName>{filteredJob.departmentName}</DepartmentName>
              <JobsContainer>
                {filteredJob.jobs.map(({ title, id, location }: Job) =>
                  <Card
                    key={id}
                    id={id}
                    title={title}
                    location={location}
                  />,
                )}
              </JobsContainer>
            </DepartmentContainer>,
          )}
        </Container>
      )
    }
```

However this produces results that I don't want. When I select something like `Austin, TX`, within this filtering, I'll get some results like so:
[image]

or

[image]

I'm not sure why I'm getting mixed results. I'm assuming the problem lies here in the way I'm filtering:

```
jobs.filter((job: DepartmentJob) =>
                job.jobs.some((job: Job) => job.location === selectedLocation)
              ).map((filteredJob: DepartmentJob => filteredJob)
```

My question is: how do I return all the locations that match exactly what I have as the selected value?

Comment: Where is `job.jobs` coming from?

Comment: You are also declaring `job` two times in the same scope (`job: DepartmentJob`, `job: Job`), you may try to avoid this.

Comment: @Colin `job.jobs` is a part of `props` that's being mapped out, and `jobs` is an array inside of job.  so it's `this.props.jobs.map(job => job.jobs)` Sorry for the naming. I should change it.

Comment: @Dyo Sorry for the naming. Those are two different types that I should change. I shouldn't be trying to hack this out at 3AM :( I've updated the types to try and make this clearer

Comment: @Dyo i've updated the naming.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `some`, it will return `true` if one of all elements satisfies the condition. So it doesn´t matter what is in the collection if one matches the dropdown value, it will return `true`.

**EDIT EXAMPLE**

```
jobs.reduce( (acc, current) => acc.concat(current.filter( job => job.location === selectedLocation)))
```

Comment: So i should be more specific then? Should I just not use `.some`?

Comment: You can just use `filter` and it will return an array with the elements that satisfies the condition.

Comment: You can try with combining [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and `filter` for that. Or iterates over nested arrays and filter each.

Comment: @Spacebear5000 I edit the answer, and add an example.

Comment: This somewhat works. I had to change it to this: `jobs.reduce((acc: any, curr: any) => acc.concat(curr.jobs.filter((job: any) => job.location === selectedLocation)), [])` But it's only returning an array with the location like this: `[{applyUrl: "....", department: "Retail-Texas", description: "....", id: "263501", location: "Austin, TX", …]` rather than the object like `[{departmentName: "Brand Marketing", jobs: [{ ....  matched location}]}]`

Comment: I missunderstood what you want to accomplish, perhaps something like `jobs.foreach(job => job.jobs = job.jobs.filter( job => job.location === selectedLocation))`. It's no the best syntax though.